# MySQL - changing AUTO_INCREMENT value on regular interval

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

We are doing following on regular interval (every 10 minutes) to spread out auto increment column value and also to make it slightly non guessable. This works as expected. However, I would like to know if downside of this approach including performance. Any other better way to do it. We can't randomize the value as we need column to be incremented with time.

```
alter table products AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

after 10 minutes

```
alter table products AUTO_INCREMENT = 11000;
```

after 10 minutes

```
alter table products AUTO_INCREMENT = 12000;
```

and so on

Thanks

Comment: You'd have to create a cronjob that runs every interval and updates on said interval, I guess?

Comment: that's correct. a cronjob that takes max() of the column value and adds some offset.

Comment: @Jim Why is it an issue that the internal ID is not in a sequence? Maybe you don't want to expose the ID value at all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, change the `id` as you do each `INSERT`.

```
INSERT INTO t  (id, ...)
    VALUES ( ( SELECT 
                 MAX(id) + CEIL(RAND() * 100)
                 FROM t
             ),
            ...)
```

Once you are doing that, there is no need for it to be `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: This approach will fail with multiple threads! Two thread may try to insert the same value and will fail.

Comment: A single statement outside a transaction but with `autocommit=ON`, will be a transaction unto itself.  If you would feel safer, make it 2 statements, use `FOR UPDATE`, and put in an explicit transaction.

Comment: How better it is compared to auto_increment option I am using?  I feel two transactions will make it unnecessarily complicated and inefficient